# java regular expression negate a character and replace string

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation

```
String s = "=?ISO-2022-JP?B?GyRCRZi?= =?ISO-2022-JP?B?QDg7OlWiE8?= =?ISO-2022-JP?B?JTkkT=?= =?ISO-2022-JP?B?kjaHaA?=";
String replRegex = "[^=]\\?= =\\?ISO-2022\\-JP\\?B\\?";

stringtoDecode= s.replaceAll(replRegex, "" );
```

result what I got is

```
=?ISO-2022-JP?B?GyRCRZQDg7OlWiEJTkkT=?= =?ISO-2022-JP?B?kjaHaA?=
```

but what I am expecting is

```
=?ISO-2022-JP?B?GyRCRZiQDg7OlWiE8JTkkT=?= =?ISO-2022-JP?B?kjaHaA?=
```

the character `?= =?ISO-2022-JP?B?` is missing in the result. I want `"?= =?ISO-2022-JP?B?"` to be replaced with empty string if it is not presided by `"="`.

Am I doing anything wrong here? Please suggest

Comment: Didn't you get any exception in your regex? Dangling meta-character or like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `[^=]` part is consuming the character `i`. You can capture this 'consumed' character and replace it:

```
String replRegex = "([^=])\\?= =\\?ISO-2022-JP\\?B\\?";
stringtoDecode= s.replaceAll(replRegex, "$1" );
```

[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/wXFKV5).

Note that you don't need to escape hyphens. (You need to escape hyphens only if you mean a literal hyphen in a character class and that the hyphen is somewhere in the middle of that character class.

OutPut:

```
=?ISO-2022-JP?B?GyRCRZiQDg7OlWiE8JTkkT=?= =?ISO-2022-JP?B?kjaHaA?=
```